# How to use UIPickerView on second ViewController

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

" I am creating a application for IPhone in which I have to creat a login page. after getting the response from the server..it will navigate the user to next view. in next view, i m using a UIPickerView. but it is not working.. becoz i only know that how to use it in individual app . but i dont knw how to use it in second ViewController of the application??"

Comment: Please post your code... Also what do you mean by its not working in second controller, it works everywhere ?? Please be more specific....

Comment: what is your requirement please describe clearly..

Comment: the thing is, if i m creating the PickerView application individually, in that case i knw how to code, but If i m adding PickerView in any application. i dont understand where to code, ( in main .h/.m) or ( second.h/.m) .. or do i need to implement some delegates in "delegate.h/m file????

Comment: learn oops and programming concepts maybe?

Comment: You dont know how to add  picker in view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can getPicker using this

```
-(void)getValuePicker
{
    ViewForValuePicker = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 219, 320, 266)];

    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

    UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneBtnPressToGetValue)];

    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:btn]];
    [ViewForValuePicker addSubview:toolBar];


    valuePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 216)];
    valuePicker.delegate=self;
    valuePicker.dataSource=self;
    valuePicker.showsSelectionIndicator=YES;

    [ViewForValuePicker addSubview:valuePicker];

    [appDelegate.window addSubview:ViewForValuePicker];
}
```

And its Delegete Method

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [pickerValueAry count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    NSMutableArray *ary = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:pickerValueAry];
    id str=[ary objectAtIndex:row];
    return str;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{    
    NSLog(@"selectedRowInPicker >> %d",row);
}
```

Comment: ViewForValuePicker = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 266)];

//Replace this line may be frame size is incorrect 

ViewForValuePicker = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 266)];

Comment: @Rocks -> actually i have some animation in my code, so initially i am setting y=480; and then after y=219;

Answer (score 0):

```
in .h file  this method

 UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

{

    IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
     NSMutableArray *pickerArrayType;
}

//in .m file

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
pickerArrayType = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Type 1",@"Type 2",@"Type 3",@"Type 4",@"Type 5", nil]
}


# pragma mark - picker Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 1;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView1 didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{


 lbl.text = [pickerArrayType objectAtIndex:row];

}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
  return [pickerArrayType count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [pickerArrayType objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Comment: is this the only thing i have to do????? 
I m using this in "second.xib" file... not in main.xib.  so in which .h/.m file i have to code... in first or second???

Comment: here I m not able to post my complete code due to character limitation... plz chk my code in the end of the post...