# UIDatePicker in UIActionSheet giving trouble while updating date on a label

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am new to IOS development. I am developing an app which requires a form to be filled by the user for the user details. The details includes a Date of Birth Field for which I am using UIDatePicker. I am adding those UIDatePicker and UIActionSheet programatically and wanted to update the date on a label. The dates are getting updated however they are getting overwritten on same label.

Here is the code

```
-(IBAction)dateButtonClicked:(id)sender {

    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose Date"delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Select",nil];                                                           
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view ];
    [actionSheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 117, 320, 383)];

}

- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {
    datePickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 216)];
    [datePickerView  setMinuteInterval:5];
    [datePickerView  setTag: kDatePickerTag];
    [actionSheet addSubview:datePickerView];
    datelabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    datelabel.frame = CGRectMake(55, 92, 300, 50);
    datelabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    datelabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    datelabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size: 12.0];
    datelabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat: @"MM/dd/YYYY h:mm a"];
    datelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                      [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    [self.view addSubview:datelabel];
    NSArray *subviews = [actionSheet subviews];
    [[subviews objectAtIndex:SelectButtonIndex] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 266, 280, 46)];
    [[subviews objectAtIndex:CancelButtonIndex] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 317, 280, 46)];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex != [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex]) {

        [datePickerView addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(LabelChange:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


        // UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Date" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       // [alert show];
    }
}

- (void)LabelChange:(id)sender{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    datelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
    datelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                      [df stringFromDate:datePickerView.date]];
}
```

Please let me know the changes needs to be done in order to void such problem.

Comment: what do you mean by overwritten

Comment: I mean the new changed date over write the old label date.

Comment: can you please show screen shot your your picker and label..

Comment: how would I send the screen shots here? please let me know ..

Comment: just take screenShot using cmd+shift+4 then edit your question then just find one imageUpload button over your question box

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TgAIz.png

Comment: Look at the place adjacent to DOb and you will find the overwritten dates...I think each time date is getting changed a UILabel is getting created and posed on same CGRect...

Comment: Have you checked the screenshot and code?

Comment: this is because your label is allocating again and again

Comment: have You got your problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700552/toolbar-at-the-top-of-uipickerview-in-xcode/13700757#13700757

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me like a charm !!!

### in .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EXPViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource,       UIPickerViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>{
UIActionSheet *pickerViewPopup;
UIDatePicker *pickerView;
IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;
}

- (IBAction)dateButtonClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

### In .m file:

```
-(IBAction)dateButtonClicked:(id)sender{
 [self showPickerView];
}

-(void)showPickerView {

pickerViewPopup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

pickerView = nil;
    pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0)];
    ((UIDatePicker*)pickerView).datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    ((UIDatePicker*)pickerView).date = [NSDate date];

UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[pickerToolbar sizeToFit];

NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)];
[barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
[barItems addObject:flexSpace];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];
[barItems addObject:doneBtn];

[pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
[barItems release];

[pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerToolbar];
[pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerView];
[pickerViewPopup showInView:self.view];
[pickerViewPopup setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 464)];
}

-(void)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender {
//Do something here here with the value selected using [pickerView date] to get that value
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd, MMM YYYY"];
    NSString* dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:((UIDatePicker*)pickerView).date];
   yourLabel.text = dateString;

[pickerViewPopup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];
}

-(void)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender{
[pickerViewPopup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: @ Satya P Dash: if you are creating UILabel programatically please initialize it in viewDidLoad method, not in your custom method. Because when you click the date button your custom method will be called each time, not only once. May be that is causing the problem. I tested my code and it is working fine !!! If it solves your problem don't forget to give +1 :)

Comment: No not working....First of all Done button is doing nothing... and secondly Cancel button is throwing exception...

Comment: did you copied my code or you made any changes to the code? bcaz I didn't get any problems while running above code. Plz check .h file carefully !!! if you want I can share screen shots of mine. I specially copied this code for you from my existing project and created a new project and tested. Its worked for me. I don't understand what you made wrong !!!

Comment: Just try to comment your code and place my code with out any changes. (U need to change only label variable name) !!!

Answer (score 0):

This is because whenever your `dateButtonClicked` action is fire , `datePickerView` and `datelabel` allocating again and again, so just do one thing, put  your code of `datePickerView` and `datelabel` code outside dateButtonClicked clicked , you can put in `viewDIdLoad`

You can implement delegate method of picker,

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

}
```

Comment: I tried with your code now...It worked well  ....first time it updates the date however if I try to change it ...it does not get changed...do ou know why?

Comment: have you tried changing the date second time...its not getting changed on label.....how to set action for that...Plz help...