# ToolBar button not working when add on picker view like as accessoryView

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, uipickerview, toolbar

Toolbars buttons are not working when I am adding Toolbar on picker view. It's working in iOS 6 but not in iOS 7.

```
 UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 ,0, 320, 44)];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(handleDone)];

UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                target:self
                                                                action:@selector(handleCancel)];

UIBarButtonItem *flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                          target:self
                                                                          action:nil];

[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelButton, flexible, doneButton, nil] animated:YES];

[pikerView addSubview:toolBar];
```

Comment: use the uiview and add the toolbar and uipickerview inside the uiview.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700552/toolbar-at-the-top-of-uipickerview-in-xcode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883388/display-done-button-on-uipickerview/20883575#20883575   have a look at this answer given by me

Comment: thanks for reply, but why it is happening I want to know.I knew that taking separate view and adding both thing separate will work. Rushabh put your reply as an answer so i can accept it.Need explanation for above question why is it so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UIToolbar` with the 'Done' button should be added to the `inputAccessoryView` of the view that **becomes first responder**. As the `UIView` class inherits from `UIResponder`, any view can potentially contain an `inputView` and `inputAccessoryView`. So instead of manually performing the animations programmatically, you could use the default animation behaviour that comes with the UIResponder's keyboard show/hide animation.

1. Subclass a `UIView` and override the `inputView` and `inputAccessoryView` properties and make them `readwrite`. In this example, I will subclass a `UITableViewCell`.

   ```
   // FirstResponderTableViewCell.h
   @interface FirstResponderTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
   @property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) UIView *inputView;
   @property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) UIView *inputAccessoryView;
   @end
   ```
2. Override `canBecomeFirstResponder` in your subclass' implementation.

   ```
   // FirstResponderTableViewCell.m
   - (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
       return YES;
   }
   ```
3. In your view controller, create and assign the picker view and input accessory toolbar

   ```
   // MyViewController.m
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
       UIToolbar *accessoryToolbar = [UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
       // Configure toolbar .....

       // note: myFirstResponderTableViewCell is an IBOutlet to a static cell in storyboard of type FirstResponderTableViewCell
       self.myFirstResponderTableViewCell.inputView = pickerView;
       self.myFirstResponderTableViewCell.inputAccessoryView = accessoryToolbar;
   }
   ```
4. Don't forget to assign first responder to the view when required (e.g. inside - `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`)

   ```
   [self.myFirstResponderTableViewCell becomeFirstResponder];
   ```

Hope this helps.

Reference: http://blog.swierczynski.net/2010/12/how-to-create-uipickerview-with-toolbar-above-it-in-ios/