# How to add a "Done" button with in the DatePicker Through StoryBoard?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uidatepicker

In my app i want to display UIDatePicker when user click on button.and that date save into UITextFiled.I done this things.
My problem is when date picker appears there is no done button,How can add that done button.
Upto now i tried.

```
- (IBAction)pickerAction:(id)sender
{
datePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;
datePicker.hidden=NO;
datePicker.date=[NSDate date];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(TextTitle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:datePicker];
NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"M-d-yyyy"];
selectedDate.text=[df stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
} 

-(void)TextTitle:(id)sender
{
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"M-d-yyyy"];
selectedDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                      [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
 }
```

How can i add done button with this code.
please help me.

Comment: This isn't through a storyboard but the highest voted answer here is very easy using an accessory view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700552/toolbar-at-the-top-of-uipickerview-in-xcode

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer is

```
datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
datePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;
[TextField1 setInputView:datePicker];

UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
[toolBar setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(ShowSelectedDate)];
UIBarButtonItem *space=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:space,doneBtn, nil]];

[TextField1 setInputAccessoryView:toolBar];
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to show how to dismiss the Date Picker. How about, TextField1.resignFirstResponder? I noticed below, how folk have created elaborate routines for animating the picker off the view. But the resignFirstResponder will do that for you, assuming the TextField1 has its inputView set to the picker, as in this example.

Answer (score 2):

I added a UIToolbar with a UIBarButtonItem for the 'done' button in my xib with the frame set so that it's not initially visible (y value equal to the height of the parent view).

Every time the user access the picker, I changed the frame (the y value) of the UIDatePicker and the UIToolbar with an animation so that it slides up along with the picker from the bottom of the screen similar to the keyboard.

Check out my code below.

```
- (IBAction)showPicker
{
    if(pickerVisible == NO)
    {
        // create the picker and add it to the view
        if(self.datePicker == nil) self.datePicker = [[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 460, 320, 216)] autorelease];
        [self.datePicker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];
        [self.datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
        [self.datePicker setHidden:NO];
        [self.view addSubview:datePicker];

        // the UIToolbar is referenced 'using self.datePickerToolbar'
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"showDatepicker" context:nil];
        // animate for 0.3 secs.
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

        CGRect datepickerToolbarFrame = self.datePickerToolbar.frame;
        datepickerToolbarFrame.origin.y -= (self.datePicker.frame.size.height + self.datePickerToolbar.frame.size.height);
        self.datePickerToolbar.frame = datepickerToolbarFrame;

        CGRect datepickerFrame = self.datePicker.frame;
        datepickerFrame.origin.y -= (self.datePicker.frame.size.height + self.datePickerToolbar.frame.size.height);
        self.datePicker.frame = datepickerFrame;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        pickerVisible = YES;
    }
}

- (IBAction)done
{
    if(pickerVisible == YES)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"hideDatepicker" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

        CGRect datepickerToolbarFrame = self.datePickerToolbar.frame;
        datepickerToolbarFrame.origin.y += (self.datePicker.frame.size.height + self.datePickerToolbar.frame.size.height);
        self.datePickerToolbar.frame = datepickerToolbarFrame;

        CGRect datepickerFrame = self.datePicker.frame;
        datepickerFrame.origin.y += (self.datePicker.frame.size.height + self.datePickerToolbar.frame.size.height);
        self.datePicker.frame = datepickerFrame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        // remove the picker after the animation is finished
        [self.datePicker performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this library. It is very easy to implement.

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQActionSheetPickerView

Answer (score 2):

go to the link below.

http://www.iostute.com/2015/01/create-and-use-date-picker-uidatepicker.html

i think it'll help you.

Comment: it is a tutorial in UIDatePicker

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIView` and in this `UIView` add your `Datepicker` and `Done` button. Done button create Action event and in this you will handle your `UIView` hide and show. 
Hope this helps