# How can i add a search bar as a toolbar above pickerview

Tags: swift

Hello Guys I want to achieve a search-bar above pickerView programatically as in the photo below[Example Design photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdp89.png)

Any Help is appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27707292/8201581

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inputAccessoryView` and `toolbar`.

```
let picker = UIPickerView()
picker.delegate = self
self.txtField.inputView = picker

let toolbar = UIToolbar()
toolbar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 35)

self.txtField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar

let search = UISearchBar()
let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: search)
toolbar.setItems([addButton], animated: true)
```